# Merge two data frames while using boolean indices (to filter)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, boolean

I have what may be a simple question related to syntax, but can't figure out.

I have two data frames, df1 and df2, that I'd like to a) merge on specific columns, while b) simultaneously checking another column in each data frame for a boolean relationship (>, <, or ==).

The crucial part is that I need to do both a and b simultaneously because the data frames are very large.  It does not work to simply merge the two data frames in one step, then remove the rows that don't pass the boolean logic in a second step.  This is because the merged data frame would be very, very large and cause me two run out of memory.

So, I have:

```
df1:
    Col_1   Col_2   Test_Value
0   A       B       1
1   B       A       3
2   A       B       2
3   B       A       5
4   A       B       2
5   B       A       1
```

and

```
df2:
    Col_1   Col_2   Test_Value
0   A       B       1
1   B       A       3
2   A       B       2
3   B       A       5
4   A       B       2
5   B       A       1
```

(for simplicity, the two data frames are identical)

And I'd like the to merge them, like so:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])
```

While simultaneously filtering for any row where df1['Test Value'] is less than df2['Test Value'], like so:

```
df3.loc[df3['Test_Value_x'] < df3['Test_Value_y']]
```

The result would be:

```
    Col_1_x Col_2_x Test_Value_x    Col_1_y Col_2_y Test_Value_y
0   A       B       1               B       A       3
1   A       B       1               B       A       5
3   A       B       2               B       A       3
4   A       B       2               B       A       5
6   A       B       2               B       A       3
7   A       B       2               B       A       5
16  B       A       1               A       B       2
17  B       A       1               A       B       2
```

Again, I can do this in two steps, with the code above, but it creates a memory problem for me because the intermediate data frame would be so large.

So is there syntax that could combine this,

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])
```

with this,

```
df3.loc[df3['Test_Value_x'] < df3['Test_Value_y']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1_col1 = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])
df1_col2 = pd.Series(['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df1_col3 = pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df1 = pd.concat([df1_col1, df1_col2, df1_col3], axis=1)

df1 = df1.rename(columns={0: 'Col_1', 1: 'Col_2', 2: 'Test_Value'})
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
```

**To Answer your question as above:**

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])[pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_x']
      <pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_y']]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will scale to the data set you have, but would be interested to know outcome :-)

Comment: Interesting.  That definitely works on the example data I posted.  I will try at scale shortly and post the results.  Can you explain what's happening in your solution?  It looks like it's doing the merge in the first section of the code, then doing two more merges which it's testing for inequality (less than).  Am I describing that correctly?

Comment: I based the answer on the boolean indexing section [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)  If you still don't understand I can try to explain better.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so any additional explanation would be helpful.  I think of it in two chunks.  The first is doing the merge, the second is doing the boolean indexing?  (Also, what do you call chunks of code? Clauses?)
`Chunk 1 -->  df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])
Chunk 2 --> [pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_x']
      <pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_y']]`

Comment: It is as you describe, the first chunk is the merged dataframe. `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])` The second chunk wrapped in the `[]` is the equivalent of a `where` clause such that `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_x']` is selecting a specific field and comparing it to `<` another field `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Col_1'], right_on=['Col_2'])['Test_Value_y']`

Comment: did this scale to your dataset

Comment: It did not scale, I got an out of memory error. I think because it is doing the merge 3 times: once for each side of the inequality, and then the final merge. The initial data frames aren't huge (~1.4mm rows) but the merged dataset could be a max of around 2 trillion rows (1.4 * 1.4, though likely less). I'm thinking about three strategies to scale it: 1) using some kind of lambda function to apply, 2) iterating through df1 by merging row 1 individually with df2 and then filtering before moving to row 2, or 3) using a buffer to handle the very large merged table before filtering it.

Comment: If its the same dataset you might be able to reduce it first with an aggregation by multiplying one by -1 concatenate then aggregate only returning + / - 1 then subtract subset of keys on original dataframe thus eliminates the ==